# Android: parsing huge JSON file and search optimization

Tags: android, json, repository, viewmodel

I need to make a small app that needs to parse from a raw JSON file around 200K cities.
I can't use any DB, but the user needs to be able to perform a city search.
The problem with the approach is that parsing such a big JSON file takes a long time, but I can't think of any other approach. I have a couple of requirements:

- Optimise for fast searches. Loading time of the app is not so important.
- Time efficiency for filter algorithm should be better than linear.
- The list can be preprocessed into any other representation that you consider more efficient for searches and display. Provide information of why that representation is more efficient in the comments of the code.

In my repository I have something like:

```
class CitiesRepository(private val application: Application) {
    fun getCities(): List<City> {
        val bufferReader = application.assets.open("cities.json").bufferedReader()
        val data = bufferReader.use {
            it.readText()
        }
        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
        val type: Type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<City?>?>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(data, type)
    }
}
```

and my ViewModel consists of:

```
class CitiesListViewModel(val app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    private val repository: CitiesRepository = CitiesRepository(app)
    val allCities: LiveData<List<City>> =
        liveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            val cities = repository.getCities()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                emit(cities)
            }
        }
}
```

Is there anything else (better) I can do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to load it into sqlite

Comment: no DB can be used, unfortunately

Comment: Use sqlite as your `The list can be preprocessed into any other representation that you consider more efficient for searches`

Comment: but the condition is `Database implementations are forbidden`, and thus having it into a SQLite DB is not allowed

Comment: Use sqlite in-memory to load your json into it at app load, since app load time is not restricted